# Debugging Vaadin 14 in Tomcat

Tags: java, java-8, tomcat8, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have migrated our apps from Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8. I'm investigating the technical challenges in a simple and pure Vaadin 8 (8.9.3) app that I run in an eclipse (2018-09 (4.9.0)) debug session using Tomcat (Apache Tomcat/8.0.45). The Vaadin 8 app is designed like

```
public class SimpleVaadin8GuiApp extends UI
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void init(VaadinRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "Application", displayName = "SimpleVaadin8GuiApp", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = SimpleVaadin8GuiApp.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class Application extends VaadinServlet
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to implement the same with Vaadin 14 (14.6.5). But Tomcat fails on starting with `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException` - please let me know when you need the whole exception stacks.

The following implementation can be run on jetty but using Tomcat I got the message that this cannot be run on server:

```
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base", enableInstallPrompt = false)
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    public MainView()
    {
        // Initialize components and add them
    }
}
```

For this I have also added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Running with maven `mvn tomcat:deploy` results in `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project project-base: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]`

What is required to run a Vaadin 14 app using Tomcat?

**Update - Callstack from eclipse console**

```
Jul 09, 2021 5:33:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SimpleVaadin14GuiApp]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SimpleVaadin14GuiApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3c308626]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7946c4eb]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: A `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException` is almost always caused by something else. Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: Just noting here that Vaadin 14 uses Servlet spec 3.1, so Tomcat 8.5 or newer is required.

Comment: I‘ll retry with a more recent version of Tomcat.